# Why is the block size in ResNets usually 2 or 3 layers and not more?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, references, residual-networks

[image]

Is there a reason why only 2 or 3 layers are skipped by a shortcut connection? What benefits would it have to skip more than 3 layers? I do not find an obvious answer besides that increasing the block size approximates a network without skip connections more and more so the benefits of skip connections would vanish. But maybe a bigger block size could still lead to better performance? I could not find any research on that.

Comment: See [this](https://imgur.com/LD6f1Xp) image.

Comment: This looks interesting, thank you. Could you elaborate a little bit more on how to interpret this and where this is from?

Comment: I tried researching for a valid explanation for the effect of larger block sizes. You can use my [code](https://github.com/shubham0204/Google_Colab_Notebooks/blob/main/ResNet_BlockSize.ipynb) to investigate further.